# Xamarin Forms Teechart - consistent gradient

Tags: xamarin.forms, teechart

So I have an area series which in which i want to use a gradient. I apply these settings"

```
lineSeries.LinePen.Width = 5;
lineSeries.Color = Color.Transparent;
lineSeries.AreaBrush.Gradient.StartColor = Color.FromRgb (219, 233, 255);
lineSeries.AreaBrush.Transparency = 20;
lineSeries.AreaBrush.Gradient.EndColor = Color.Transparent;
lineSeries.AreaBrush.Gradient.Visible = true;
lineSeries.LinePen.Color = Color.FromRgb (219, 233, 255);
lineSeries.AreaLinesPen.Visible = false;
```

And the result is this:
[image]

The problem is that I want the gradient to be consistent in the whole area, and now a single gradient line is drawn below each point. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Area.GradientRelative property](http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/net/lib/html/SteemaTeeChartStylesAreaGradientRelativeProperty.htm) for that, for example:

```
  lineSeries.GradientRelative = false;
```